# Is there any alternative for Trigger After Insert

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns in a table, one is Auto Identity set, and other one should be created as a string value with Id as Pad right, I have created a trigger but my lead is saying Triggers impact the performance, and to not create, is there any alternate for Triggers that would not effect Database performance at the same time do what I am expecting it to be done.
My trigger is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AfterInsert
   ON  InspectionItems
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @InspectionItemNumber nvarchar(20), @InspectionItemId int

    select @InspectionItemId = ins.InspectionItemId FROM INSERTED ins;

    update InspectionItems set InspectionItemNumber = 'T' + RIGHT('00000'+CAST(InspectionItemId AS VARCHAR(5)),6)
    where InspectionItemId = @InspectionItemId
END
GO
```

Is there any alternate for trigger and doing the same and preserve the performance - thanks in advance.

Comment: A computed column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
alter table InspectionItems 
add InspectionItemNumber = 'T' + RIGHT('00000'+CAST(InspectionItemId AS VARCHAR(5)),6)
```

What are the differences?

1. If not persisted or indexed, the computed column will be evaluated at `select` time instead of `insert` time.
2. The computed column value will update if the columns it depends upon update, or if you change the expression. This would not be true if the column was only calculated with an insert trigger. So there's a behaviour difference there
3. You have a choice as to whether or not you want to actually persist the computed column. You can also put an index on a computed column. These choices aren't always available, it depends on the column expression. Your expression is deterministic and precise, so all options are open.

One last point of advice on triggers in general: Your trigger as written is not safe. You assume that only a single row will be inserted at a time. But an insert statement is a set based operation. The `inserted` table can have more than one row. How would you assign multiple rows worth of `InspectionItemId` values to the `@InspectionItemId` variable?

You need to write your triggers with set based operations in mind. This means, for example, joining on the `inserted` and `deleted` tables, rather than assigning expected-scalars to variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it a persisted, computed column:

- drop your existing column `InspectionItemNumber`
- then execute this SQL to create the computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.InspectionItems
ADD InspectionItemNumber AS 'T' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(InspectionItemId AS VARCHAR(5)), 6) PERSISTED;
```

Now every time you insert a new row, SQL Server itself will compute this value and surface it as column `InspectionItemNumber`